# How can you make a strip of mesh parts bend according to the distance from an object individually?

Tags: rigging, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

So I'm working on a dragon rig, and I'd like to control the spikes on its back.
I thought it would be wise to do it by a distance from a certain separated bone, and that the scale of the bone would be the range, so that it would be possible to control the direction / position as well as the distance.
I don't want to use a specific rig for this.
I tried to do something like this using geometry nodes and it didn't go so well, mainly because I hardly understand anything about it.
I would appreciate any help or guidance.
[image: cool stripe of spikes on back of dragon]

Oh, and just to be clear, I want every part to bend, not the strip itself.